# Error: spawn ENOENT for video upload

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to upload **video** with **node.js**. While I upload **video**, I got this error::

```
  events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
  Error: spawn ENOENT
     at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)
```

My Code in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/X3JAQvuZ)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to install **FFMPEG**, you can follow the following steps::

1. SSH into your instance and become root:

   ```
   sudo su -
   ```
2. Go to the the `/usr/local/bin` directory

   ```
   cd /usr/local/bin
   ```
3. Inside the `/usr/local/bin` directory, create an **ffmpeg** directory

   ```
   mkdir ffmpeg
   ```
4. Go into the new directory

   ```
   cd ffmpeg
   ```
5. Go to static build directory at http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/64bit/ and pick the 
   latest version of **FFMPEG** - as of this writing, it was `ffmpeg.static.64bit.2014-07-16.tar.gz`

   ```
    wget http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/64bit/ffmpeg.static.64bit.2014-07-16.tar.gz
   ```
6. The file should now be in /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg. Untar it...

   ```
    tar -xzf ffmpeg.static.64bit.2014-07-16.tar.gz
   ```
7. Run it and check what the latest version is

   ```
   ./ffmpeg -version
   ```
8. If you want to be able to execute FFMPEG from any directory, simply create a symlink into /usr/bin like this:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg
   ```

   Hope your problem will fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with events.js using Gulp:

```
[19:59:06] Starting 'jekyll-async'...

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)
```

I've spent hours looking for solution, but I was looking in wrong direction.
In my case problem occurred because I forgot to install gems from my Gemfile (after complete system reinstall).

So, cure for me was:

```
gem install jekyll
```

Hope this helps somebody)